# using apt-get for specific version not working

Tags: curl, apt

I use the following code which works ok

```
apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends curl git  && \
```

Now I want to put a version for curl and use the following

```
apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends curl=7.68.0 git  && \
```

here I got version not found error ...any idea ?
i try with older version and got the same results ...

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/releases.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You use Ubuntu 
Linux Ubuntu bionic 7.58.0  binary
Linux Ubuntu cosmic 7.61.0  binary
Linux Ubuntu disco  7.64.0  binary
Linux Ubuntu trusty 7.35.0  binary
Linux Ubuntu xenial 7.47.0  binary
so in Ubuntu 7.68.0 not available as latest version 
Available in

```
Mac OS X    7.68.0  source  MacPorts
Mac OS X    7.68.0  source  Homebrew

Linux T2    7.68.0  source  T2
Linux Suse i386 7.68.0  binary  openSUSE
Linux Suse i386 7.68.0  devel   openSUSE
Linux Suse i386 7.68.0  libcurl openSUSE
Linux Suse x86_64   7.68.0  binary  openSUSE
Linux SliTaz    7.68.0  source  SliTaz
Linux Slackware x86_64  7.68.0  binary  Slackware
Linux Slackware ARM 7.68.0  binary  ARMedslack
Linux Slackware i386    7.68.0  binary  Slackware
Linux Redhat RHEL6 x86_64   7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Redhat RHEL7 x86_64   7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Redhat RHEL6 i386 7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux PLD   7.68.0  source  
Linux OpenEmbedded  7.68.0  source  
Linux NixOS x86_64  7.68.0  binary  NixOS
Linux NixOS 7.68.0  source  NixOS
Linux Mageia    7.68.0  binary  Mageia
Linux Linux From Scratch    7.68.0  source  
Linux Gentoo    7.68.0  source  
Linux Frugalware    7.68.0  binary  
Linux Fedora 13 x86_64  7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 14 x86_64  7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 15 x86_64  7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 16 x86_64  7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 20 x86_64  7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 21 x86_64  7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 26 x86_64  7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 13 i386    7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 14 i386    7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 15 i386    7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 16 i386    7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 17 i386    7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 18 i386    7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 19 i386    7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 20 i386    7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Fedora 26 i386    7.68.0  binary  Paul Howarth
Linux Arch StrongARM    7.68.0  binary  Arch Linux
Linux Arch x86_64   7.68.0  binary  Arch Linux
Linux Alt   7.68.0  binary  
Linux Alt   7.68.0  devel   
Linux Alt   7.68.0  libcurl 
Linux Alt   7.68.0  source  
HPUX 11.00 HPPA 7.68.0  binary  connect.org.uk
HPUX 11.11 HPPA 7.68.0  binary  connect.org.uk
HPUX 11.23 ia64 7.68.0  binary  connect.org.uk
Haiku   7.68.0  source  
FreeBSD 7.68.0  source  
DOS 7.68.0  binary  Michael Kostylev
AIX 5.3 7.68.0  binary  Michael Felt

NetBSD  7.68.0  source  
OpenBSD 7.68.0  source  Christian Weisgerber
Solaris i386    7.68.0  binary  OpenCSW
Solaris i386    7.68.0  libcurl OpenCSW
Solaris Sparc   7.68.0  binary  OpenCSW
Solaris Sparc   7.68.0  libcurl OpenCSW
Solaris Sparc64 7.68.0  binary  OpenCSW
Solaris Sparc64 7.68.0  libcurl OpenCSW
Solaris x86_64  7.68.0  binary  OpenCSW
Solaris x86_64  7.68.0  libcurl OpenCSW
VMS 8.3 Alpha   7.68.0  binary  John E. Malmberg
VMS 8.4 Alpha   7.68.0  binary  John E. Malmberg
VMS 8.4 ia64    7.68.0  binary  John E. Malmberg
VMS 7.3 VAX 7.68.0  binary  John E. Malmberg

Windows 32 bit  7.68.0  binary  the curl project
Windows 32 bit  7.68.0  binary  Chocolatey
Windows 32 bit  7.68.0  binary  Viktor Szakats
Windows 32 bit  7.68.0  binary  Dirk Paehl

Windows 64 bit  7.68.0  binary  the curl project
Windows 64 bit  7.68.0  binary  Chocolatey
Windows 64 bit  7.68.0  binary  Viktor Szakats
Windows 64 bit  7.68.0  libcurl Vcpkg
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that the version isn't just 7.68.0 but tied to your specific flavor of linux. For me, my current version is 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.2. So the correct command would be:

`apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends curl=7.81.0-1ubuntu1.2 git  && \`

You can find detailed version in at least three ways.

1. Run `apt-cache policy <package>` for the specific package. This will provide the packages available for your flavor of linux.
2. Download with no version and check package name grabbed within the download script. For example:

`Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 curl amd64 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.2 [194 kB]`

3. Click into the specific binaries on the curl download page (https://curl.se/download.html). You will see the specific package there.